# C++ make specific target

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to make specific executable file with designate target.
I create a sample project as below

```
./main_a.cpp
./main_b.cpp
./include
./include/fun.h
./src
./src/fun.cpp
./Makefile
```

main_a.cpp

```
#include "fun.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fun();
    printf("AAA\n");
}
```

main_b.cpp

```
#include "fun.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fun();
    printf("BBB\n");
}
```

fun.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void fun();
```

fun.cpp

```
#include "fun.h"

void fun()
{
    printf("test ");
}
```

The content of Makefile is listed as blow

```
OBJDIR := obj/
SRCDIR := obj/src

CXX_INCLUDE = -I. -I ./include

CXX_SRCS := $(shell find src/ -name "*.cpp")

CXX_OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), ${CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o})

EXE_AA = main_a
EXE_BB = main_b

aa: $(OBJDIR)
aa: $(SRCDIR)
aa: CXX_SRCS += main_a.cpp  # take main_a.cpp as main
aa: $(EXE_AA)

bb: $(OBJDIR)
bb: $(SRCDIR)
bb: CXX_SRCS += main_b.cpp  # take main_b.cpp as main
bb: $(EXE_BB)

$(EXE_AA): $(CXX_OBJS)
    @echo "Building AAA :"
    $(CXX) $(CXX_OBJS) -o $@ 
    @echo "Building Finished:"


$(EXE_BB): $(CXX_OBJS)
    @echo "Building BBB :"
    $(CXX) $(CXX_OBJS) -o $@ 
    @echo "Building Finished:"

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) $(CXX_INCLUDE) -c $^ -o $@

$(SRCDIR):
    mkdir -p $(SRCDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR) $(EXE_AA) $(EXE_BB)
```

What I want is if I run **make aa**, then generate **make_a**
but errors occurred show as below:

```
mkdir -p obj/
mkdir -p obj/src
g++ -I. -I ./include -c src/fun.cpp -o obj/src/fun.o
Building AAA :
g++ obj/src/fun.o obj/main_a.o -o main_a 
g++: error: obj/main_a.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'main_a' failed
make: *** [main_a] Error 1
```

Same errors are raised as well when I run **make bb**

How should I modify my Makefile so that I can generate the specific executable file with designate target, thanks

Comment: Have you tried printing out `$(CXX_OBJS)`? You can do this with the `$warning` function (IIRC).Is it really what you think it is?

Comment: When it executes  $(CXX) $(CXX_OBJS) -o $@ , it prints  g++ obj/src/fun.o obj/main_a.o -o main_a

Comment: You don't seem to have a rule for building `obj/main_a.o`. I suspect that it should have been built from `./main_a.cpp`, but the builtin implicit rule for that builds `./main_a.o` from `./main_a.cpp` and not `obj/main_a.o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, as clearly stated in [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html), target-specific variables are only available inside the recipe of a rule.  They are not available in the prerequisite list of a rule.

So in this situation:

```
$(EXE_AA): $(CXX_OBJS)
        @echo "Building AAA :"
        $(CXX) $(CXX_OBJS) -o $@ 
        @echo "Building Finished:"
```

the version of `CXX_OBJS` in the prerequisites list doesn't see the new value added by the target-specific variable:

```
aa: CXX_SRCS += main_a.cpp
```

and so make doesn't know it needs to build that object file.  However the `CXX_OBJS` value in the recipe *does* see the new value from the target-specific variable, and it tries to link that object file which doesn't exist.  If you changed your linker rule to be more "correct", like this:

```
$(EXE_AA): $(CXX_OBJS)
        @echo "Building AAA :"
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ 
        @echo "Building Finished:"
```

then you'd see the problem, because the link line wouldn't contain the extra object either.

*ETA*

There are lots of possible ways to do this.  One is to simply list the object file directly and not use target-specific variables at all:

```
$(EXE_AA): $(OBJ_DIR)main_a.o $(CXX_OBJS)
        @echo "Building AAA :"
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ 
        @echo "Building Finished:"
```

Another is to use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(EXE_AA): $$(CXX_OBJS)
        @echo "Building AAA :"
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ 
        @echo "Building Finished:"
```

(note the double-dollar sign in the prerequisite list).  You could also use generated include files, recursive makefiles, or `eval`.

Comment: MadSt, thanks for answering my questions. I have tried the line, and I found that main_a.o is exactly not included for linking. So to make generate the specific file what I want, how should I modify my Makefile to achieve that ? Thanks

Comment: MadSt, I made it. Thanks very much!